# Limit Rotation bone constraint resets rotation when it hits 180 degrees

Tags: bones, constraints

I'm trying to limit rotation in one way but allow almost full rotation counter wise to that locked rotation. So far I have achieved what I was trying to do, but it doesn't allow full rotation for some reason, at around 180 degrees it just resets the rotation.
It seems to be a well known limitation, is there any good workarounds? I am using a stretch to so maybe I should make that tracked bone limited in location?

Edit: So I resolved the issue by using drivers with "if else" script. You can just make values change depending on rotation of bone, so that when it's close to 180 degrees drivers change the value to something that allows more rotation.

Comment: Hello, yes it looks like it's a limitation, but maybe show your armature so that someone can find a workaround. Similar question here, with some answers: https://blenderartists.org/t/rigging-how-to-limit-a-bone-to-180-degree-rotation/621354/5